# Will a Tripped GFCI wired at the end of a circuit kill power to all receptacles in that circuit? (Panel Breaker not tripped)

Tags: electrical, gfci

I have a panel circuit with a 20A breaker. This circuit has 4 regular outlets and 1 20A GFCI outlet wired at the end of the circuit. The GFCI outlet is 15 years old and is an outside receptacle with the rest of the circuit is located inside my garage[image]. The GFCI outlet has 1 wire with a Black and White conductor (+Grd). While running an extension cord to this GFCI outlet to temporarily run my Pool Pump, the GFCI tripped (Faulty Extension cord confirmed). The entire series of outlets also lost power although the Panel breaker (20A) did not trip. The GFCI will not reset either. (Diagram included) Will replacing the GFCI correct my no power issue for the entire circuit?

Comment: If the outlets were wired in series like old Christmas light bulbs that would happen. As a thought for you when you replace this outlet, either A) replace the breaker with a GFCI breaker and put in a regular (but _Weather Resistant_) outlet outside, or B) replace the next to last outlet with a new GFCI outlet and put in a regular WR breaker outside. The GFCIs will last much longer indoors than out. I think many here will be quite surprised to discover that your outdoor GFCI has lasted _this_ long!

Comment: BTW- well done for your first question. Including the diagram is helpful and something most folks don't think of doing without prompting! While you're waiting for an answer (not just a comment), take the [tour] and read through the [help] so you can learn to get the most from the site & its format.

Comment: The GFCI is most certainly miswired.  So even with the extension cord removed it won't reset?  That suggests quite possibly a loose or failed ground wire connection.

Comment: @FreeMan  The GFCI would need to be on the first outlet since all are in the garage and need to be GFCI protected

Comment: @CarlWitthoft GFCIs do not use ground (GFCI receptacles have a connection so they can pass it on - notice how GFCI breakers do not connect to ground). It's legal to install GFCI receptacles (in certain cases) without any ground connection and label them "no equipment ground" and they will still work just fine.

Comment: Check all the outlets on this circuit to see if they were connected using the backstabs. A direct short can burn a backstab in the clear and open the entire circuit.  Correct if needed.

Comment: @JACK good point. I _thought_ that, but failed to _type_ that.

Comment: @nobody quoting wiki, "In North America, GFI receptacles can be used in cases where there is no grounding conductor, but they must be labeled as "ungrounded". An ungrounded GFI receptacle will trip using the built-in "test" button, but will not trip using a GFI test plug, because the plug tests by passing a small current from line to the non-existent ground."  Since we're not sure about the OP here,  ensuring proper ground connections is a really good idea in any case and may well be related to his particular problem

Comment: @FreeMan  I do that a lot too.  I can fix the problem faster than I can type out the solution,, lol.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft Sure, grounds are important. But saying "a loose or failed ground wire connection" could cause this particular symptom is just plain incorrect.

Comment: Answered by @Freeman! I replaced the end GFCI and the circuit is whole. I also purchased an additional GFCI for the recommended redundancy. I will look at the tabs as suggested by @Jack to ensure integrity of the circuit as well. The replaced GFCI had significant corrosion at the gound wire connection (This GFCI was grounded.) Thank You!

Comment: Backstabs on a 20 amp circuit never have been legal. If all the receptacles are out I would double check the first one then go back to the panel   With failures like this it is the last working receptacle or the first dead one, since the string is bad the breaker or neutral connection is bad if the first receptacle is ok. Code doesn’t require updating for redundant GFCI’s and this can cause problems code covers new installs.

Answer (score 2):

### No, it will not.

In fact, there’s probably nothing wrong with the GFCI.

What happened is you temporarily overloaded the circuit due to said munged extension cord, and this overload blew a fuse in one of the other receptacles.

OK, “fuse” is the wrong word, obviously receptacles do not have fuses... but it fails exactly the same way.  One of the receptacles has a poor connection.  The overload of the extension cord burned the connection out.

### Find the bad connection

The most likely cause is “back-stab” connections - where the wire is jabbed into a hole in the back of the recep. (Mind you those should never be used on a 20A circuit).  It can also happen from a loose screw connection.

Go to each recep, identify any backstabs, forcibly pull and twist them out, and search them for burn or spalling marks.  If you find one, gotcha!  Move that wire to the side screw by stripping a little more insulation off and shaping it into a J-hook to go around the screw. Set it clockwise so the screw tightens not spreads the wire.

### Then move the GFCI so it does protect the downline

The sockets on a GFCI are on the LOAD side of the GFCI - they are in the protected zone.  You can put other connections in the protected zone; just attach them to the LOAD terminals of the GFCI.  That is the only thing LOAD should ever be used for; all other connections should be to LINE.

So, relocate this GFCI recep to one of the indoor outlets.  That will get it out of the weather and make it last a lot longer.  The closer to the panel it is, the more it will  protect - but don’t allow a refrigerator or freezer, fire alarm, sump pump or radon pump to be on GFCI protection, as they are safety devices.  Other than that, garage outlets should be on GFCI if possible.